# Write to Process with Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

I'm developing a UI with Qt Creator that controls an OPC Server.

Check Input Function OPC Server:

```
void runUserInterface()
{
// we have an endless loop waiting for a keyboard input
bool end = false;
_tprintf(_T("The server is running.\n"));
usage();

while(!end)
{
    // variables for input purposes

    //tstring function;
    tstring input = _T("");
    //getline(tcin, input);
    //tstringstream inputStream(input);

    cin >> input;

        if (input == _T("x") || input == _T("q") || input == _T("X") || input == _T("Q"))
        {
            // exit if one of the four exit characters is hit
            _tprintf(_T("Shutdown\n"));
            end = true;
        }
        if (input == _T("s"))
        {
            // exit if one of the four exit characters is hit
            _tprintf(_T("Shutdown\n"));
            end = true;
        }
}
}
```

When I run it in Visual Studio, it's working and the Server shuts down. When I write to the Process in Qt Creator, the UI stops working.

```
#include "control_window.h"
#include "ui_control_window.h"
#include "configuration_window.h"

#include "configuration_window.cpp"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QWidget>

#define CMD_EXIT "q"

control_window::control_window(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::control_window)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

control_window::~control_window()
{
delete ui;
}

void control_window::on_control_window_Exit_clicked()
{
m_opc_ua_server->write(CMD_EXIT);
m_opc_ua_server->waitForBytesWritten();
}
```

What's wrong?

Edit 1:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBttV.jpg)

The UI just crashes when on_control_window_Exit_clicked() is triggered, the OPC Server is still running though.

```
//QProcess opc_ua_server;
QStringList arguments;
//m_opc_ua_server->startDetached(opc_ua_server_filepath, arguments);
//m_opc_ua_server->start(opc_ua_server_filepath, arguments, QIODevice::ReadWrite);


//m_opc_ua_server = new QProcess(this);
m_opc_ua_server->setProgram("C:/Users/Max/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/OPC UA Server 0.3/Debug/OPC UA Server 0.1");
m_opc_ua_server->start(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

I've tried to start the OPC Server differently, and to get the input in the Server differently.

```
  //getline(tcin, input);
    //tstringstream inputStream(input);
    cin.clear();
    cin >> input;

    //getline(cin, input);

    //tcin >> input;
```

Edit 2:

Ok, I think the problem is in the UI, I made a small test program and the same error occurs.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass();
~MyClass();
void checkinput();

private:

};

MyClass::MyClass()
    {
    }

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::checkinput()
{
}

string input = "";

void checkinput()
{
cin >> input;
}

int main()
{
bool end = false;
while (!end)
{
    checkinput();
    if (input == "j")
    {
        end = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried and whether you get any error messages?